# ASP.NET Web API - Undecorated HttpActionResult is treated as POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Could somebody tell me the default http method for the undecorated action method?

I have this controller with the undecorated action method

```
[RoutePrefix("sample")]
public class SampleController : ApiController 
{
    [Route("sample")]
    public Task<IHttpActionResult> SampleMethod() 
    {
        await Task.Run();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When I try to call it as `GET` method, I am getting an error: "does not support GET".

When I tried it calling with `POST`, I am able to call it.

I tried tracing it why its treating it as `POST` but I no luck

I hope somebody can enlighten me...

Comment: @marc_s - whats the similarity of my question to the other question? does those have the same cause as this question?

Comment: @marc_s - those related question doesn't even solved this question. why closed?

Comment: @marc_s - thanks for the existing post. I got what I need